# How much time ManageIQ takes to reflect data After adding Provider(Azure,AWS etc.)

Tags: open-source, redhat, manageiq

I added Azure Provider and AWS provider to the ManageIQ its been more than a Day no data about Instances reflected in ManageIQ. As the provider is Authenticated but still no report displayed about Instances in ManageIq with Azure provider and AWS provider.

Answer (score 0):

The time it takes for the initial refresh to complete depends on both the provider type and the amount of inventory in the provider.  For most typically sized Azure or Amazon providers, usually it takes on the order of 10s of minutes or less.  If you are not seeing anything after a day, there is very likely a problem.  For more information, take a look in the evm.log, aws.log, and/or azure.log found in /var/www/miq/vmdb/log.